# Testing React component that relies on externally imported js with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, enzyme

I've got a bit of an annoying issue here while trying to test a react modal class component in Enzyme, the class uses bootstrap and jQuery, application below.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // @ts-ignore
    $('#' + this.props.modalId).modal('toggle');
    this.addKeydownHandler();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.removeKeydownHandler();
    // @ts-ignore
    $('#' + this.props.modalId).modal('toggle');
}

addKeydownHandler = () => {
    $(document).on('keydown', (e: any) => { this.preventTabKey(e) });
}

removeKeydownHandler = () => {
    $(document).off('keydown', (e: any) => { this.preventTabKey(e) });
}
```

I'm importing everything needed in my index file so they are accessible across the whole website as below.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
import * as jquery from 'jquery';
(window as any).jQuery = jquery;
import 'popper.js';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```

And I'm calling Enzyme's mount as below.

```
var children = <div className="fgsr" ><p>Test</p></div>
    var modal = Enzyme.mount(
        <Modal modalId={"testId"} >
            {children}
        </Modal>
    );
```

The problem is when I just mount the Modal for testing I get various errors - "TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function" and "Bootstrap js needs jQuery", if I just add the bootstrap js

The immediate/hacky fix is to simply add the imports below to the Modal class, but obviously don't want to include multiples of large files just to get tests to run.

```
import * as jquery from 'jquery';
(window as any).jQuery = jquery;
import '../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```

Is there a workaround for this or a way to add extra imports to an Enzyme mounted wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way of injecting externally imported js files into an enzyme wrapper for testing but there's a good workaround. I simply created a utility test component with all the dependencies imported that took children as props and simply returned the children in that component as below.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as jquery from 'jquery';
(window as any).jQuery = jquery;
import 'popper.js';
import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';

export interface Props {
    children: JSX.Element;
}

const DependencyContainer = ({ children }: Props) => {
    return (children);
}

export default DependencyContainer;
```

And then in my test class just wrapped my component in that container.

```
var modal = Enzyme.mount(
        <DependencyContainer>
            <Modal>
                {children}
            </Modal>
        </DependencyContainer>
    );
```

This way no additionally files need to be imported into production code.

Answer (score -1):

I think jQuery is not being initialized in the "$" variable (and your component needs it).

You can try this:

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
```

Comment: "The immediate/hacky fix is to simply add the imports to the Modal class, but obviously don't want to include multiples of large files just to get tests to run."